# C++ macro only works when preprocessed to a file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros

I am trying to create a matching mechanism for the new `std::optional<T>` in C++. I've written the following macro:

```
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define CAT_(x, y) x##y
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(EXPAND(x), EXPAND(y))
#define if_opt__(xalt, bval, x, y)  \
auto xalt = y;                      \
bool bval = true;                   \
if (xalt.has_value())               \
for (auto x = xalt.value(); bval; bval = false)
#define if_opt_(xalt, x, y) if_opt__(xalt, CAT(xalt, _b), x, y)
#define if_opt(x, y) if_opt_(CAT(x, __LINE__), x, y)
```

And I've created the following example program for it:

```
std::optional<int> get(int a) {
    if (a < 0) {
        return {};
    }
    return a;
}

int main(void) {
    if_opt(a, get(0)) {
        std::cout << "optional matched!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile the program, I get errors like 'redefinition; different basic types'. Then I preprocessed it to a file, copied the result and it compiled and worked just fine. The macro evaluated to:

```
auto a24 = get(0);
bool a24_b = true;
if (a24.has_value()) 
    for (auto a = a24.value(); a24_b; a24_b = false) {
        std::cout << "optional matched!" << std::endl;
    }
```

Why does it not compile using the macro itself? I'm using MSVC.

Comment: Modify macros to instead generate a string containing their arguments (clearly delimited) and debug using that.  If you have args-in, you can then emulate calling the next step.  Hopefully something interesting happens...  but maybe msvc is just broke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your `CAT` macro performs extra expansion should be corrected:

```
//#define EXPAND(x) x // not needed
#define CAT_(x, y) x##y
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
```

When it is being expanded at some point it produces expression `EXPAND(x)##EXPAND(y)` which breaks further expansion as ## can only work with plain tokens and won't even try expanding `EXPAND`.

As why it works when preprocessing to file? Probably because VS has very fancy (and non-conformant) way of handling stuff. Gcc will give you better diagnostics even when preprocessing to a file.